# How to copy strings from ifstream to vector<string> elegantly?

Tags: c++, algorithm, copy, iostream, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("test.txt");

    vector<string> coll;

    typedef istreambuf_iterator<char> IStrBufIter;
    copy(IStrBufIter(fin), IStrBufIter(), back_inserter(coll)); // Error! Why?
}
```

---

The question is commented in the code.

The error I get is:

```
oi.cpp:15:62:   required from here
error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >::char_type {aka char}’ to ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_reference {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}’ [-fpermissive]
```

The error messages that follow are too many to paste here. Please refer to the Error msg on gcc 4.7 http://pastebin.com/anKQqL00

Comment: If there is an error you need to post it.

Comment: `copy` is from `<algorithm>`

Comment: Do you want to copy individual characters, or strings? If strings, what strings?

Comment: @Pubby, the error messages is too many to paste here.

Comment: @jogojapan, I want to copy strings.

Comment: @xmllmx Error message or it never happened. ;)

Comment: Your istreambuf_iterator is giving you chars, your back_inserter is expecting std::strings.

Comment: @xmllmx What strings? Strings containing single characters? Or strings containing words? If words, how to you define the boundaries between words?

Comment: @jogojapan, the boundaries are identified by '\n', which can be recognized by the iostream automatically.

Comment: @xmllmx There is a misunderstanding about what `istreambuf_iterator` does. It does not read lines (neither by recognizing `\n` nor in any other way). It iterates through the individual characters of the input stream. If you want lines, you need to explain that in the question.

Comment: @jogojapan, the title of the post has said I want to copy strings from fin to vector<string>.

Comment: @xmllmx But strings could be anything. _Lines_ is a very special case of strings.

Comment: @xmllmx the first `error` message is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put the contents of a file into a vector just loop through it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("test.txt");

    vector<string> coll;
    string str;
    while(getline(fin,str))
        coll.push_back(str);
}
```

Probably easier to deal with and self-explanatory.

Comment: However, I want to use std::copy here. Any idea?

Comment: @xmllmx This puts the _lines_ of the input into the vector. Is that what you want?

Comment: @xmllmx: If you want lines, you'll have to develop a special input iterator that reads a line at a time, or maybe you can find a public implementation of something like that.  The standard library doesn't have one.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley wouldn't `istream_iterator<string>` rather than `istreambuf_iterator` work instead?

Comment: @Rapptz: Not for getting lines.  `istream_iterator` uses `operator>>`, and with strings, that means reading whitespace delimited tokens. Any whitespace, not just newlines.

Comment: @xmllmx why do you *want* to use `std::copy`? It's much easier to use this approach for what you're doing.

Comment: Another option would be defining a special type that encapsulates a string, and has an implicit conversion to `std::string`, but its overload of `operator>>` reads in a whole line instead of just a word.  Then you could use `istream_iterator<YOUR_STRING_TYPE>`.  That would probably be simpler than implementing an iterator, but less interesting and less useful.

Answer (score 4):

Consider what your `copy` is doing. It's repeatedly calling `coll.push_back(someChar);`

`coll` is a vector of `strings`. You are trying to push a `char` into it. You can't construct a `string` from a `char`.

Also, you should be using `istream_iterator` here, not `istreambuf_iterator`. You can either make `coll` a vector of `char`s, or if you are aiming to get each word in the file into your vector of strings (which I suspect you might be) you can change `istream_iterator<char>` to `istream_iterator<string>`.

Or, better yet, you can construct the vector in the first place using your iterators:

```
 vector<string> coll(istream_iterator<string>(fin), istream_iterator<string>());
```

Comment: `istreambuf_iterator<string>` wouldn't compile, I don't think, or at least [I can't get it to compile](http://ideone.com/fXaO2t).

Comment: I cannot compile istreambuf_iterator<string> too.

Comment: @xmllmx corrected - see edited answer.

Comment: @Dave, I can not compile vector<string> coll(istream_iterator<string>(fin), istream_iterator<string>());!

Comment: @xmllmx, Look up the most vexing parse.